# Why Dataset columns are not recognised with CSV on Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: csv, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a csv file, with no header.
its 1496 rows of data, on 2 columns in the form:

> Real; String

example:

> 0.24; "Some very long string"

I go to New - Dataset - From local file
Pick my file, and No header csv format

But after its done loading i get an error message i cant decrypt:

> Dataset upload failed. Internal Service Error. Request ID:
>   ca378649-009b-4ee6-b2c2-87d93d4549d7 2015-06-29 18:33:14Z

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Does your CSV need to use a semicolon separator?  AzureML may be expecting a comma separator in a comma separated values file.

Comment: That is a good point, ill give it a try. My concern was the long string which has commas.

Comment: EDIT: that did actually work, yet created som other issues, but atleast some i can work with

Answer (score 2):

At this time Azure Machine Learning only accepts the comma `,` seperated, American style CSV.

You will need to convert to a comma separated CSV

Comment: I am getting a similar error (on automatic validation), when trying to use this data set: https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/blob/master/airline-safety/airline-safety.csv