# Azure ML: How to save and process CSV files with semicolon as delimiter?

Tags: csv, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, escaping

Azure ML support says to me that delimiter must be comma, this would cause too much hassle with data having semicolon as separator and with a lot of commas in the cell values.

So how to process semicolon separated CSV files in Azure ML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Dataset columns are not recognised with CSV on Azure Machine Learning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123035/why-dataset-columns-are-not-recognised-with-csv-on-azure-machine-learning)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Azure ML only accepts the comma `,` separated CSV. Do a little work around.
Open your data file using a text editor. (Notepad will do the trick). Find and replace all semicolons with 'tab' (Make it a TSV) and the commas in data values may not occur a problem then. Make sure to define that the input is a TSV; not a CSV.